# Selenium after compile py2exe, Firefox doesn't start

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

i wrote a BOT for a webgame, works perfectly when i run it with IDLE, firefox launches and does the job. But after compiling with Py2exe firefox doesn't launch anymore...Any ideas ?

PS : Firefox 45.0.2 , Selenium 2.53

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098527/make-exe-file-from-python-selenium-tests have a look this page.

Comment: I already included all files of selenium...Or i wouldn't ask....

Comment: I mean in my dist/selenium i included wedriver.xpi and webdriver_prefs.json but still it cannot find Firefox...

Comment: Well I can not help you, but I've done little destkop app using selenium and tkinter,  I converted it to exe with pyinstaller and works properly.

Comment: I have same issue with previously working bot. Why are there so many downvotes? Please elaborate some details in the question so that problem gets solved and we get less downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Hum finally i solved it, was my mistake, i was copying th wedriver.xpi and webdriver_prefs.json in the wrong directory...

So you need to compile it without making a Zipfile (or won't work) and copy the 2 files in the good directory :

from : C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox

to : /dist/selenium/webdriver/firefox

Setup.py example:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe



setup(
name='Web BOT',
version='1.0',
description='BOT',
author='Author',
author_email='mymail@mail.com',
url='',
windows = [{
        "script":"Myscript.py",
        "icon_resources": [(1, "myicon.ico")],
        }],
options={
    'py2exe':
        {
            'skip_archive': True,
            'optimize': 2,
        }
}
)
```

And then everything works fine !